# Sort arr[] in PHP 50 indexes to 7 indexes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is an array that I want to sort. This is taken by an HTML table that is already stored in the database. But here it has 50 indexes. That's the thing I want to reduce to seven.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] =>  
            [2] =>  
            [3] =>  
            [4] =>  
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data          
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data          
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data      
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data    
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data   
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data            
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data          
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data       
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => 
            [38] => 
            [39] => 
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
        )

)
```

I tried with **for loops**, **foreach** loops to sort this array shows up to 7 indexes. It should be like this.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => data
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] =>  
            [2] =>  
            [3] =>  
            [4] =>  
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] =>  
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] =>  
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => data 
            [2] => data
            [3] => data
            [4] => data
            [5] => data         
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

)
```

What did I try is,

```
for ($row = 0; $row <= sizeof($arr); $row++) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < 7; $col++) {
            $aar[] = $arr[$row][$col];
        }
    }
```

This method wasn't worked. What is the way or any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep x amount of elements from each sub-array, you can use [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$newArray = [];

foreach($arr as $sub) {
    // The example array you say you want have 8 elements, indexes 0-7
    // so start with index 0 and take 8
    $newArray[] = array_slice($sub, 0, 8);
}
```

Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/WhFm4

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one possible solution to your problem. Just define the key limit in if condition. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
$row = [
    [
        '',
        'data',
        'data',
        'data',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
    ],
    [
        '',
        'data',
        'data',
        'data',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
    ]
];

$reducedArray = [];

foreach ($row as $col) {
    $tempArray = [];

    foreach ($col as $innnerKey => $innerValue) {
        // Define your index limit here.
        // As you can see I have set the limit to 7
        if ($innnerKey <= 7) {
            $tempArray[] = $innerValue;
        }

    }

    $reducedArray[] = $tempArray;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<br/>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($reducedArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I just used 2 arrays just for demonstration. You can increase the number of inner Array